# Convert Hex colors to RGB in Swift and count elements

Tags: swift, swift2, uicolor

I've seen a few answers that say to use `countElements` or `count` on this line, but I get errors in my code for that on the line:

`if (count(cString) != 6) {`

Saying **"Cannot invoke `count` with an argument list of type `String`"**

I've tried a few other ideas, but am not finding the right solution, any ideas?

Here's the full function:

```
func colorWithHexString (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercaseString

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString = (cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(1)
    }

    if (count(cString) != 6) {
        return UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    var rString = (cString as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
    var gString = ((cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(2) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
    var bString = ((cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(4) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)

    var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
    NSScanner(string: rString).scanHexInt(&r)
    NSScanner(string: gString).scanHexInt(&g)
    NSScanner(string: bString).scanHexInt(&b)


    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(1))
}
```

Comment: I wonder why people always insist to define colors as strings. The task is much easier if you keep using integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cString.characters.count` instead.

Apple have updated `String` in Swift 2 so that it no longer conforms to the `CollectionType` protocol, which `count` is defined on. Instead, Swift strings now expose a collection of characters through the `characters` property.

This is because strings do not necessarily behave like other collections - e.g. if you add a number to an array, you expect the count of that array to increase, but adding certain unicode characters to a string - such as accents, for example, may not
increase the length of the string.

Full details are here https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30

The amended method would be:

```
func colorWithHexString (hex:String) -> UIColor {
 var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).uppercaseString

  if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
    cString = (cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(1)
  }

  if (cString.characters.count != 6) {
    return UIColor.grayColor()
  }

  let rString = (cString as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
  let gString = ((cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(2) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
  let bString = ((cString as NSString).substringFromIndex(4) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)

  var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
  NSScanner(string: rString).scanHexInt(&r)
  NSScanner(string: gString).scanHexInt(&g)
  NSScanner(string: bString).scanHexInt(&b)


  return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(1))
}
```

Note some `vars` have become `let`s since they are never mutated

Comment: When I've tried:  if (cString.characters.count !=6) {
            return UIColor.grayColor()
        } ...it gives me errors like "Expected `,` separator" on the first line.  If I actually add the `,` then I still have an error on that line that tells me "`!=` is not a prefix unary operator error"... any ideas?

Comment: Odd, a test of that works for me. I think there's probably a typo somewhere else in your code. Try creating a simple method just using `characters` to check the length of a string and see if you get the same error

Comment: Makes sense!  Thanks!!